# php json_decode return [object Object]

Tags: php, json, object

I have a problem with JSON data in PHP. I need to use data from this JSON in my SQL statement. When I'm trying to debug it with echo(var_dump, or print_r is not working too) command the output with is

```
{"records":"tekst","name":"[object Object]"}
```

This is a JSON structre:

```
            {
                records: 'tekst',
                name: {
                    imie: 'imie1',
                    nazwisko: 'nazwisko1'
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to decode this by `json_decode()`, but I have an error

> "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given".

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: When I use valid JSON, [it works](http://3v4l.org/CTeQO)

Comment: The error @user3250669 is getting suggests that the already parsed JSON-data structure (PHP array) is being passed to `json_decode`, rather than the (unparsed) JSON string. [edit]

Answer (score 1):

PHP manual about JSON and the format required: **[function.json-decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**. basically, double quotes only and names must be quoted.

a demonstration of conversion using PHP.

So, you supply the json string that looks like, with the whitespace removed, like this:

```
{records:[{id:1,name:'n1'},{id:2,name:'n2'}]}
```

Which is an object containing an array with two entries that could be arrays or objects.

Except, **it is not a valid JSON string** as it contains **single quotes**. And PHP wants all the names in double quotes, as in "id":1.

So, possible PHP code to recreate that, assuming arrays as the inner entries is:

```
$json = new stdClass();
$records = array();
     $entry = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'n1');
     $records[] = $entry;

     $entry = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'n2');
     $records[] = $entry;
$json->records = $records;

$jsonEncoded = json_encode($json);
```

Which, when 'dump'ed looks like:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'records' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => string 'n1' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => int 2
          'name' => string 'n2' (length=2)
```

Now, the string that structure produces is:

```
{"records":[{"id":1,"name":"n1"},{"id":2,"name":"n2"}]}
```

Which looks similar to yours but is not quite the same. Note the names in double quotes.

However, if **your json string looked the same** then PHP could decode it, as is shown below:

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonEncoded);

var_dump($jsonDecoded, 'decoded');
```

Output: Note all objects...

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'records' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => int 1
          public 'name' => string 'n1' (length=2)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'id' => int 2
          public 'name' => string 'n2' (length=2)
```

We may want arrays instead so use the true as the second parameter in the 'decode'

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonEncoded, true);

var_dump($jsonDecoded, 'decoded with true switch');
```

Output: with arrays rather than objects.

```
array
  'records' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => string 'n1' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          'id' => int 2
          'name' => string 'n2' (length=2)
string 'decoded with true switch' (length=24)
```